# how to get selected row and column number after setgraphic of textbox in tableview in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have set `TextField` in column as below in `Tableview` 
setGraphic(textField);
then I have added `changeListener` to get updated text, so now I also want to get row and column number.

```
setGraphic(textField); 
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
 public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue,
         final String oldValue,final String newValue) 
    { 
      System.out.println("old "+oldValue+" and new : "+newValue); 
  // Here,How can i get the particuler row number
 } });
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are selecting one `TableView` cell, and you want to get its column and the row index.

Get the `TableView`  from your [TableCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html#getTableView%28%29):

```
TableView table = this.getTableView();
```

Then,  the [TablePosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TablePosition.html) from the **first** [SelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html):

```
   TablePosition firstCell = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
```

Finally,  the column and row index :

```
 firstCell.getColumn() //int
 firstCell.getRow()  //int
```

Comment: No, I am not selecting any row .In every row I have set textfield as graphic of cell . whenever i change the text of any row i want to get thats change text and that particular row number and column nuber.
so i have added listener to get that change text but i cant get that particular row number at that time.

Comment: You have to put the complete description of your problem, and what have tried , to get relevant answers.